# &:first-of-type li not working in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-class

I'm trying to get the first `li` element in a `ul` with the class `breadcrumbs` to have a red background, and it's not working. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but what?

```
.breadcrumbs {
            margin-left:-30px;
            p {
                display:inline;
            }
            li {
                display:inline;
                &::before {
                    content:'>> ';
                }

            }   
            &:first-of-type li {
                background:$red;                                
            }                   
        }
```

Comment: That will result in .breadcrumbs:first-of-type li which will select all li elements in the first of type .breadcrumbs element. Maybe?:

li {
  &:first-of-type {
    ...
  }
}

Comment: This is why you need to be looking at the compiled result to make sure it contains what you expected it to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the pseudo selector in the wrong place.

```
.breadcrumbs {
            margin-left:-30px;
            p {
                display:inline;
            }
            li {
                display:inline;
                &::before {
                    content:'>> ';
                }
               &:first-of-type {
                  background:$red;                                
               }
            }   

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `&` refers back to the parent selector. Your rule would parse into:

```
.breadcrumbs:first-of-type li {
    background: red
}
```

But if I understand your question correctly you only want to style the first `li`, not all `li`'s in the first `ul`. Try this

```
.breadcrumbs {
    ...

    li:first-of-type {
        background: red;
    }
}
```